# how to use lambda as "Developer Authenticated Identities" to serve custom auth flow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

Serverless is wonderful, but I have a little confuse if possible or how to leverage lambda as my "server" to handle custom auth flow? So that the serverless conception are more perfect. But not need to run an EC2 instance only to handle custom auth flow.

Thanks

P.S. my custom flow will have ID and password auth case and mobile phone number auth case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is the answer I'm searching for.

no need you to have your own authentication server, this can do for you.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html

do authorization for you
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints

thanks great guys